# NPM Error The value "4294967295" is invalid for option "family"

Tags: node.js, express, npm, dns, qemu

**Problem**

I can't seem to install and packages using npm. It seems to be a DNS query issue. Has anyone found a way to fix this?

**Software**

- node --version v10.18.1
- npm --version 6.13.4

**OS**

- Virtualization: qemu
- Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-55-generic
- Architecture: x86-64

**Logs**

```
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', 'webpack' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v10.18.1
4 verbose npm-session 854255086166d555
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for webpack@^4.17.0 The value "4294967295" is invalid for option "family"
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 49ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 3593ms
10 verbose stack TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value "4294967295" is invalid for option "family"
10 verbose stack     at lookup (dns.js:112:11)
10 verbose stack     at net.js:1004:5
10 verbose stack     at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:294:19)
10 verbose stack     at lookupAndConnect (net.js:1003:3)
10 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.Socket.connect (net.js:938:5)
10 verbose stack     at Object.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1165:13)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createConnection (https.js:120:22)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createSocket (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/_http_agent.js:265:26)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createSocket (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/agent.js:77:11)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.addRequest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/_http_agent.js:239:10)
10 verbose stack     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:249:16)
10 verbose stack     at request (https.js:289:10)
10 verbose stack     at fetch.Promise (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:54:17)
10 verbose stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
10 verbose stack     at fetch (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:41:10)
10 verbose stack     at retry (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/index.js:332:14)
11 verbose cwd /var/www/magellan/app
12 verbose Linux 4.15.0-55-generic
13 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "webpack"
14 verbose node v10.18.1
15 verbose npm  v6.13.4
16 error code ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE
17 error The value "4294967295" is invalid for option "family"
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is somehow related to [this issue described in the balena forum](https://forums.balena.io/t/oddity-while-testing-balenacloud-with-qemu-x86/115062):

the mentioned exception comes probably from [the dns.js in node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/dns.js#L118) and may be a result from [a "mysterious" variable intialization](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/dns.js#L108):

```
family = options.family >>> 0;
```

It looks like that an *undefined* value for family gets evaluated to "4294967295" instead of "0" while using QEMU.

If you have access to the code for the underlying call (at net.js:1004:5), maybe you can do a similiar workaround and add a fixed value for this family-parameter to the "lookup" function call.